# How can I force sed to continue parsing when it hits an "invalid" character?

Tags: sed, character-encoding, special-characters

I have a big playlist in `.pls` format (created with `deadbeef` playing software) which also contains some badly-encoded strings. Whether this is a bug in `deadbeef` or one of its plugins does not really interest me, though, since I just want to cut off from a certain position to the end of the line using `sed`.

However, this is easier than it looks at first sight, since `sed` will instantly **interrupt** parsing once it hits a character it deems "invalid":

```
$ cat archives.pls | grep --perl-regexp Lika.*rar.*02
rar:///home/andy/audio_compressed/world/ru/Lika Star - Ya (RUS 2001).rar:2001- �/02 ���.mp3
```

This is the original line, unmodified. Now let's try `sed` on it, to extract the path (note: this is for a script I'm almost finished with to check for "dead" audio files in the directory tree, i. e. those that do no longer exist)

```
 $ cat archives.pls | grep --perl-regexp Lika.*rar.*02 | sed -e 's/^\(zip\|rar\|7z\):\/\///' -e 's/\(\.\(zip\|rar\|7z\)\):.*/\1/'
 /home/andy/audio_compressed/world/ru/Lika Star - Ya (RUS 2001).rar�/02 ���.mp3
```

Ugh. This obviously did not work, though the regular expression **is** definitely correct (since it can be proved to work fine with so-called "valid" characters). The `rar�` actually comes from a contraction of originally `rar:2001- �`, which indicates that `sed` parsed from the colon via the "2001-" to the blank, then stopped abruptly at the invalid � character.
Still, there is the question left why doesn't `sed` just ignore what encoding it is and parses anyway? I mean, we want everything to be cut off after the colon following the "rar", so it ought to be safe to assume that `.*` *does* 
definitely stand for *any* character?

*NOTE: Please refrain from "seemingly elegant" solutions using `cut` in your answers. Been there, done that. Instead, you had better consider that we're on a UNIX-type OS and we may even legitimately use strange file names that involve artists that originally spell ":wumpscut:" or the like. In other words, there might be a colon something in-between as well, which is why it would not be a good idea to statically cut off at the first colon we come across after the `(zip|rar|7z)://`.*

Comment: What are those characters? Please pipe the grep output through `od -c` or `od -t x1`

Comment: *will instantly interrupt parsing once it hits a character it deems "invalid"* -> There may not be a choice.  E.g. UTF-8 includes **multibyte characters**, and if you try to process something that's encoded wrongly by that standard, you can hit a byte (!= a character) that doesn't make sense, meaning it is impossible to interpret the next byte because there's no valid context to interpret it in.  Note that you haven't reported the actual error here, just a lot of noise about it.

Comment: Your question wording is misleading and unclear.  As your example demonstrates, `sed` parsed the input just fine since you got the `.mp3` which came after the questionable characters.  Your real question is "Why doesn't `.` match � in a `sed` regex, and how do I match �?".  Then, it becomes obvious that the real question is what on earth "�" is.  I second glennjackman's suggestion - run `od` on the input.  Also what is your shell's locale (`echo $LANG`)?  In all likelihood running `LANG=C sed` will probably work.

Answer (score 3):

As goldilocks already commented above, UTF-8 is a **multibyte** variable-width encoding. Each character might consist of up to four bytes. After an invalid byte you can at best *hope* that the next byte might start a new character.

`sed` tries to match characters not bytes. As the invalid byte is no character and the `.` only matches characters it will not match and your result is absolutely correct.

You have to find out what encoding is used for that file. (The `file` command might help you with this.)
Setting the environment variable `LANG` to the correct value should be enough for `sed` to work the way you intended it to. In your case probably `LANG=C` should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

Set your `LANG` environment variable to some UTF-8 encoding string like `LANG='en_US.UTF-8'`. Here, on Mac OS X 10.6.8, it is `LANG='C'` that causes GNU `sed` 4.2.1 to stop parsing as described in the question. GNU `sed` 4.2.2, on the other hand, just works fine.

Another modification that works for me (on Mac OS X 10.6.8) is to replace the regex part `:.*` with: `:\([^[:print:]]\|[[:print:]]\)*` (POSIX character class).

```
echo $'rar:///home/andy/audio_compressed/world/ru/Lika Star - Ya (RUS 2001).rar:2001- \357\277\275/02 \357\277\275\357\277\275\357\277\275.mp3' > archives.pls

(
export LANG='C'
#locale charmap
cat archives.pls | grep --perl-regexp 'Lika.*rar.*02'
cat archives.pls | grep --perl-regexp 'Lika.*rar.*02' | gsed -e 's/^\(zip\|rar\|7z\):\/\///' -e 's/\(\.\(zip\|rar\|7z\)\):.*/\1/'    # GNU sed 4.2.1
cat archives.pls | grep --perl-regexp 'Lika.*rar.*02' | gnused -e 's/^\(zip\|rar\|7z\):\/\///' -e 's/\(\.\(zip\|rar\|7z\)\):.*/\1/'  # GNU sed 4.2.2
cat archives.pls | grep --perl-regexp 'Lika.*rar.*02' | gsed -e 's/^\(zip\|rar\|7z\):\/\///' -e 's/\(\.\(zip\|rar\|7z\)\):\([^[:print:]]\|[[:print:]]\)*/\1/'
)


# output:
# rar:///home/andy/audio_compressed/world/ru/Lika Star - Ya (RUS 2001).rar:2001- �/02 ���.mp3
# /home/andy/audio_compressed/world/ru/Lika Star - Ya (RUS 2001).rar�/02 ���.mp3
# /home/andy/audio_compressed/world/ru/Lika Star - Ya (RUS 2001).rar
# /home/andy/audio_compressed/world/ru/Lika Star - Ya (RUS 2001).rar

#--------------

(
export LANG='en_US.UTF-8'
#locale charmap
cat archives.pls | grep --perl-regexp 'Lika.*rar.*02'
cat archives.pls | grep --perl-regexp 'Lika.*rar.*02' | gsed -e 's/^\(zip\|rar\|7z\):\/\///' -e 's/\(\.\(zip\|rar\|7z\)\):.*/\1/'    # GNU sed 4.2.1
cat archives.pls | grep --perl-regexp 'Lika.*rar.*02' | gnused -e 's/^\(zip\|rar\|7z\):\/\///' -e 's/\(\.\(zip\|rar\|7z\)\):.*/\1/'  # GNU sed 4.2.2
cat archives.pls | grep --perl-regexp 'Lika.*rar.*02' | gsed -e 's/^\(zip\|rar\|7z\):\/\///' -e 's/\(\.\(zip\|rar\|7z\)\):\([^[:print:]]\|[[:print:]]\)*/\1/'
)

# output:
# rar:///home/andy/audio_compressed/world/ru/Lika Star - Ya (RUS 2001).rar:2001- �/02 ���.mp3
# /home/andy/audio_compressed/world/ru/Lika Star - Ya (RUS 2001).rar
# /home/andy/audio_compressed/world/ru/Lika Star - Ya (RUS 2001).rar
# /home/andy/audio_compressed/world/ru/Lika Star - Ya (RUS 2001).rar
```